# Confusion about mapDispatchToProps

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  locationUpdate: position => dispatch(locationUpdate(position)),
  groupFetch: city => dispatch(groupFetch(city)),
  groupFetchCoordinates: (location, selectedDistance) => dispatch(groupFetchCoordinates(location, selectedDistance))
})
```

I am trying to understand mapDispatchToProps with regards to react-redux and stumbled upon this code. I have looked into the documentation on mapDispatchToProps and so far what I understand is functions are being declared (locationUpdate and groupFetch) which themselves invoke dispatch calls. My confusion is if mapDispatchToProps is written in a manner such as shown above, then where do the arguments 'location and selectedDistance' come from? Is it just a declaration such that if you were to call these methods you can just type groupFetch(city) for instance? Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the parameters that *you* pass in when you call these functions to dispatch them:

`props.groupFetchCoordinates("San Francisco", 25)`

However, note that [we now specifically recommend using the React-Redux hooks API as the default instead of `connect`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api).